# Referencing Material 3 material_dynamic_* colors causes crash below Android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, material-you

Material 3 dynamic colors `@color/material_dynamic_*` do not seem to exist on android versions that do not natively support dynamic color (i.e. < Android 12). This causes a crash with `Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.real:color/material_dynamic_primary20 with resource ID #0x7f060204` when inflating any layout XML on Android < 12.

My application's theme inherits from `Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar`, and I'm using the latest Material support library.

Is there an alternative to using these color resources that work on older android versions that do not natively support Material dynamic colors?

Comment: For all devices which do not support Material You, you can use a theme with the baseline color scheme values hardcoded. https://m3.material.io/styles/color/static/baseline